# Angular let- doesn't set a local variable

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-ng-if, angular-template

I'm trying to set a local variable inside an `<ng-template>`, but it seems that `let-` doesn't work.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thy9a2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data as d">
<ng-container *ngIf="false; else testBlock"></ng-container> 
<ng-template #testBlock let-x="d">
  data:{{data | json}} <br />
  d:{{d | json}} <br />
  x:{{x | json}} <br /> <!-- let-x didn't work !! -->
</ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

**Notes**

The `data` object is more complex than this example, so I need to set a local variable to a deep property of data to avoid repeatedly access it.

i.e: using `{{x.something}}` instead of `{{data.payload.prob1.prob2.something}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an ngTemplateOutlet context to pass variables to the ng-template. 
ngTemplateOutletContext should be an object, the object's keys will be available for binding by the local template let declarations.

```
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="false ? originalBlock : testBlock" 
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{data: data}"> 
</ng-container>

<ng-template #originalBlock let-d="data">
  data:{{data | json}} <br />
  d:{{d | json}} <br />
</ng-template>

<ng-template #testBlock let-x="data">
  data:{{data | json}} <br />
  x:{{x | json}} <br />
</ng-template>
```

Comment: it worked, but why we should pass `[ngTemplateOutletContext]="{data: data}"` instead of `[ngTemplateOutletContext]="data"`, even if `data` itself is an object?

Comment: Yeah you can pass directly. but do remember that only the keys of the object will be available in the ng-template